# RegEx match only if selected words present in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to regEx and i could not find a solution to this. I wanted to match a string if any of two selected words present in that string.

I wrote like this

```
perl -e ' "text   -aborted" =~ m/(.*)-[failed aborted]/; print "\n\n$1\n\n";'
```

but the problem is, it is getting matched even if any of the charecters in failed or aborted is present in the string,
eg

```
 perl -e ' "text   -fa" =~ m/(.*)-[failed aborted]/; print "\n\n$1\n\n";'
```

i wanted to match only for  exact match of failed  or aborted, some one please help on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets `[]` in regular expressions behave differently from what you're expecting here.  They match a single character, and that character can be any of the characters within the square brackets.  For example, if you wanted to match a single lower-case vowel, you could do that with:

```
m/[aeiou]/
```

What you're looking for is an alternation.  This will search for the word "failed" or "aborted":

```
m/(failed|aborted)/
```

That is, your choices are each separated by pipes `|`, and surrounded with parentheses `()`.  You can chain these together too:

```
m/(many|different|acceptable|words)/
```

Answer (score 3):

Try an *alternation*, like this

```
m/(.*)-(?:failed|aborted)/
```

The `(?:...)` sequence groups items in the same way as parentheses but doesn't form a capture.

In addition you could avoid capturing trailing spaces using

```
m/(.*?)\s*-(?:failed|aborted)/
```

which uses a non-greedy quantifier (with the additional `?`) to allow the pattern to match as *few* characters as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` introduces a character class. Any character listed matchess the class. You need an *alternation*:

```
"text -aborted" =~ /(.*)-(?:failed|aborted)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets denote a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), i. e. (as you correctly noticed) a regex token that matches one of the characters inside the brackets.

You want simple [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`), together with non-capturing parentheses (`(?:...)`):

```
perl -e ' "text   -aborted" =~ m/(.*)-(?:failed|aborted)/; print "\n\n$1\n\n";'
```